# converting unique values in a row to separate rows

Tags: perl, awk

I have a dataset as follows:

```
      Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4  Col5

 Row1 apple banana pears pears pears
 Row2 Tiger Tiger  Lion  Lion  Tiger
```

And restructure them as below. Extract unique row values and make them as rows and fill them as 1 and 0 based on their presence and absence in the original data

```
      Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4 Col5
Apple  1       0     0    0    0 
Banana 0       1     0    0    0
pears  0       0     1    1    1
Tiger  1       1     0    0    1  
Lion   0       0     1    1    0
```

I tried to get the unique values in the data by using R

```
data<-data[!duplicated(data)]
```

But not sure how to set the unique values as rows and match them to get 0 and 1.

Comment: Sorry about that I did try something basic where I got the unique values but was not sure how to proceed. Thought it was too basic to post.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{delete ks; 
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
          {ks[$i]; 
           a[$i,i]=1}
        for(k in ks) 
          {printf "%s", k; 
           for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%d", OFS, +a[k,i]; 
           print ""}}' file | column -t

apple   0  1  0  0  0  0
banana  0  0  1  0  0  0
pears   0  0  0  1  1  1
Lion    0  0  0  1  1  0
Tiger   0  1  1  0  0  1
```

not sure the `Cols1` header part the file, if so print first two lines as is and start processing `NR>2`